# How to calculate the new camera position and rotation in a 3d space to get the exact same view of an 3d object after it is moved?

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, geospatial, spatial, camera-calibration

I have a 3d object (Obj) and a camera (Cam) points to the object. The camera FOV, resolution, position and rotation are given along with the object's position and rotation.
Then, we change Obj's position and rotation by some random numbers (known). What I need is to get the exact the same view of Obj as it is in its original position by only changing Cam's position and rotation.
How to calculate the new camera's position and rotation?

Comment: this isnt possible unless the scene you are observing is a plane. Otherwise there will be occlusions and other perspective effects that will make the image/object look distorted.

Comment: if you parented the camera to the object it would retain the position

Comment: @Micka, I only care about the view of the object (ignore whatever in the scene)

Comment: @BugFinder, is there any specific formula or api I can use to get it assuming I am using opencv?

Comment: Why are you using openCV for something happening in game in Unity?

Comment: Why would you calculate anything, if you parent the camera to the object the camera becomes in effect like a fixed selfie stick it moves with it..

Comment: @ErikOverflow, BugFinder, sorry for the confusion. This is more a camera calibration problem than a game in Unity, I just use unity to do the experiment.

Comment: @hengstar: The object IS (part of) the scene. Imagine a head where your camera is faced to the nose once slightly from left and the other time dlightly from right, you cant get the lost/occluded information magically.

Comment: ok, if you are interested in camera motion, just apply the inverse of the object motion to your camera. See openGL rendering pipeline (or similar) if you are interested in camera-world coordinates, transformations, etc.

Comment: @Micka, thanks for the info. The actual effect needed is exact like what the follow camera does like BugFinder mentions parent the camera to the object. I may just need the formula of that.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but what about nesting the camera inside the object you translate/rotate and then remove it after it's modified? This should keep the view exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** `if Obj moves`

Create an attribute `Vector3 deltaPosition` in Cam's code. Initialize it by evaluating the distance between Cam and Obj.

```
void Start(){
    deltaPosition = transform.position - Obj.transform.position;
}
```

In `Update()`, make sure you keep Cam the same distance from Obj, where it is:

```
void Update(){
    transform.position + deltaPosition;
}
```

---

**(2)** `if Obj rotates`

Suppose Obj was at euler angles (x0, y0, z0) and rotated to euler angles (x1, y1, z1). All you have to do is to rotate `deltaPosition` (x1 - x0, y1 - y0, z1 - z0) degrees around Obj's position. To do this, you must also store the initial rotation of Obj in another attribute `Vector3 objRotation`:

```
void Start(){
    deltaPosition = transform.position - Obj.transform.position;
    objRotation = Obj.transform.eulerAngles;
}
```

And make sure it is correctly adjusted every frame:

```
void Update(){
    deltaPosition = RotatePointAroundPivot(
        deltaPosition, 
        Obj.transform.position,
        Obj.transform.eulerAngles - objRotation
    );
    transform.position + deltaPosition;
    objRotation = Obj.transform.eulerAngles;
}

public Vector3 RotatePointAroundPivot(Vector3 point, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 angles) {
    return Quaternion.Euler(angles) * (point - pivot) + pivot;
}
```

This should do the trick.